# Facebook Php SDK - getUser() return always 0 but working fine on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Creating a simple login page with facebook login button
After login getUser() must return the uid of logged in user but it is still returning 0

I am following this [9lessons tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/09/working-with-facebook-sdk-permissions.html) also.it works fine on **local host** but **online server** it always returns 0.

I have seen many similer quetions but none of them helped me.

Please help to find out whats the problem

Comment: Do you solve this problem?

Comment: If you use it on a live server you need to reset the permissions for that app.Best is to create a new app and use the new keys.